SQL: group by to select max observation
Imagine you have the following table named city:



market
product
cost




A
1
54


A
2
62


A
3
38


B
1
12


B
2
12


B
3
5



I need the most expensive product for each market, i.e.:



market
product
cost




A
2
62


B
1
12


B
2
12



I know this SQL query doesn't work:
SELECT *, MAX(cost)
FROM city
GROUP BY market

The point isn't finding a solution (that's pretty easy I think).
My question: is there a specific reason why the SQL language doesn't evolve to allow the query above to find the result?

If this query worked, what would you expect for select *, min(cost), max(cost) from ...?

@Dogbert actually it doesn't work (as I specified)... my point is: why sql doesn't evolve to make it work

Yes, that's my question: if it worked, what would you expect my query to return?

what I show in the second table

Is the question about how to find the most expensive market or about why the language does not support your query. If the former, the error message is pretty self-explanatory. If the latter, it's because you're selected columns that are not grouped nor aggregated, so what should the values be in those columns? (basically why Dogbert is asking)

By the way your query will work fine in SQLite if you have a single max/min in select, but not if you have more than 1 (can't find the link, but it's documented somewhere iirc). with t(a, b) as (values (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 4), (2, 3)) select *, max(b) from t group by a;

Your second table shows what could happen with max(cost), but if you select min(cost), max(cost) that result doesn't make sense.

I'd consider RANK() window function.

@HenryWoody "so what should the values be in those columns?"... I'd like the row to be duplicated (or better, both the obs have to be selected), since there is not a rule to find the "correct" value in the column

@jarlh can you help me with an example?

@HenryWoody I get the point... but why SQL doesn't want to save in the result the two records? I understand this is impossible in an "average aggregation"... but with max/min it is very helpflul

Why doesn't every language just guess what you want? Because computer languages have syntax to prevent ambiguity and contradictions. Being flexible to your simplistic use case would cause ambiguity and increased complexity in many other use cases. Not to mention the debug HELL it would introduce if syntax errors (be they typos or otherwise) were "accommodated" with arbitrary behaviours

@MatBailie thank you! yours is one of the most interesting answers (since I'm not looking for a solution of the problem, I know there are a lot of ways to solve it)... so it's just a matter of "safety" (that I don't agree with since duplicated rows in a join with a non unique key are pretty common), you just need to know what you're doing and I still fine more useful my "desire of output"... but I don't want to be the ruler

Then you've never worked on a large project and had to debug subtle mistakes. Making the language looser to allow certain use cases take less typing would GUARANTEE debugging complex use cases to be MUCH harder. The language can already do what you want, asking it to "evolve" so that you don't have to type as much would make it much worse in terms of robustness. Fail hard and fail fast are desirable attributes, not shortcomings.

If you are getting error "'city.idt' is invalid", it is because when you are using MAX or SUM or other similar functions in SQL, you should specify other columns that you want in group by.
For example
SELECT MAX(cost) AS cost, market 
FROM city 
GROUP BY market

So there we want market so we should specify it in group by
the result will be
cost     market
---------------
64          A
12          B

if you want to get other columns without specifying them in the group by:
SELECT
    *
FROM
    city
WHERE
    cost IN (SELECT DISTINCT MAX(cost)
             FROM city
             GROUP BY market) 
ORDER BY
    market ASC


You can use a subselect or a CTE to get the results. First get the maximum price in the market, and then list the products
Here you have the query with the subselect:
SELECT c.* 
FROM city c 
JOIN (select market, max(cost) as maxcost From city group by 1) s 
ON c.market=s.market AND c.cost = s.maxcost;

And using CTE:
with maximumCost as (
select market, max(cost) as maxcost From city group by 1)
SELECT c.* 
from city c 
JOIN maximumCost m ON c.market=m.market AND c.cost=m.maxcost;

In both cases you get the desired result:
 market | product | cost
--------+---------+------
 A      |       2 |   62
 B      |       1 |   12
 B      |       2 |   12
(3 rows)


WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
  city ( market, product, cost ) AS
    ( Select 'A', 1, 54 Union All
      Select 'A', 2, 62 Union All
      Select 'A', 3, 38 Union All
      Select 'B', 1, 12 Union All
      Select 'B', 2, 12 Union All
      Select 'B', 3,  5
    ) 

Some basic facts about SQL standard regarding aggregate functions and GROUP BY:

An aggregate function is a function that performs a calculation on a set of values, and returns a single value.

Select Max(cost) as cost From city;
/*
cost
----
  62  */


The GROUP BY clause splits the result-set into groups of values and
the aggregate function can be used to return a single value for each group.

Select Max(cost) as cost From city Group By market;
/*
cost
----
  62
  12  */

... the same query just with market fetched too
Select market, Max(cost) as cost From city Group By market;
/*
market  cost
------  ----
A         62
B         12  */

... Your query
SELECT *, MAX(cost) FROM city GROUP BY market

... which is converted into
SELECT market, product, cost, MAX(cost) FROM city GROUP BY market

... should return 1 row per market to follow the standard - so, this breaks the rule of returning a single value for each group.
That is why all non-aggregated columns in Select list should be in Group By clause...
One of the options could be using IN operator on two columns ...
--     S Q L :
Select *
From   city
Where (market, cost) IN ( Select   market, Max(cost) as cost
                          From     city
                          Group By market )

/*  R e s u l t :
market  product cost
------  ------- ----
A             2   62
B             1   12
B             2   12    */


Use RANK() window function, partition by city:
select market, product, cost
from
(
  select market, product, cost,
         rank() over (partition by market order by cost desc) rnk
  from city
) dt
where rnk = 1

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/R4NT6G_y
